# 16.04 - How do I change GRUB resolution to 1920x1080?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual-booted with Windows 7, now I want to change the wallpaper on GRUB but GRUB only supports 640x480 resolution.

I want to change the resolution to 1920x1080 so I can put 1920x1080 wallpapers, also my laptop supports 1920x1080 not to mention it even supports 1440p!

My specs:

PC - Alienware M15x
RAM - 8GB
GPU - NvIDA GeForce 260M
CPU - Intel i5

Comment: Because you have Nvidia and most likely proprietary drivers, I strongly advice against.

Comment: But he also has Intel i5 which probably means HD3000 or HD4000?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Indeed, which makes it even worse.

Comment: @CelticWarrior LOL.... Indeed indeed! My resolution defaults to 1024x768 or something like that and I force it to 640x480 for nice big text :)

Comment: @user589808 probably a dual-card machine.